# How to specify git repository branch name in fastlane continuous integration

Tags: xcode, git, integration, continuous, fastlane

I am going to use fastlane for continuous integration for our iOS project (Xcode). We want to build the app from different branches of our git remote repository. How can I specify the branch name for build the app?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your CI system, as you usually don't want to switch branches yourselves after the CI system checked out the source code.

Comment: We have iOS codebase (Xcode project) with multiple targets. We want to build different targets from different GIT repository branches. What we want is, we have to specify git branch name and target name when we want a build. Any ways to do this using fastlane?

Comment: You can always `sh "git checkout -b something", however this sounds quite risky

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add the integration to the CI of the correct repositories, and add CI rules (in your CI config file) to determine what it should run depending on the branch you're in.