# Is it possible to build from a specific branch or tag using Fastlane?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, fastlane

My git repository contains both the app code and the Fastlane files. I would like to add a lane that can take a user-provided option, `git checkout` the branch or tag, and run the normal Fastlane build and deploy commands as normal.

However, there appears to be two blocking issues:

`git checkout` does not seem to be natively supported by Fastlane. [Conceptually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954776/how-to-specify-git-repository-branch-name-in-fastlane-continuous-integration), it seems to be against the intentioned design of the system.

If I switch the branch (such as through a third-party action) and the Fastfile is an older revision, and lacks the lane that originally started, what happens? Does the Fastlane runner or harness keep a copy of the original Fastfile to prevent that situation?

Comment: Any Solution?...